# IUIAutomation GetFocusedElement error code not found

Tags: windows, visual-c++, ui-automation

I am utilizing Microsoft's UI Automation APIs to retrieve the currently focused element within my application. However, there are instances where the API returns an error, which is not documented in their [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-error-codes). As a result, I am unable to debug the issue. For example, I am encountering errors with codes -2147467259 and -2147220991.

```
IUIAutomation *pUIAutomation;
CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, __uuidof(IUIAutomation), (void **)&pUIAutomation);
IUIAutomationElement *focusedElement;
HRESULT hr = pUIAutomation->GetFocusedElement(&focusedElement);
std::cout << hr << std::endl;
```

I would appreciate any assistance in understanding the issue.

Comment: -2147467259 is 0x80004005 aka `E_FAIL`: a generic "something went wrong" error. -2147220991 is 0x80040201 aka `UIA_E_ELEMENTNOTAVAILABLE`: it is too documented in their official documentation.